# How to fix missing locale files on Manjaro?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, locale

I'm running Manjaro Gnome and installed some updates with the package manager. Since then I keep getting these messages in the console:

```
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
(anon):12: character not in range
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

Running `locale` gives me this output:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

When I run `sudo locale-gen` I get an error message that files or directories do not exist

```
Generating locales...
  de_DE.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `i18n_ctype': No such file or directory
```

when I comment out `de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.gen` (then the only not commented out line is `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`), I get:

```
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
```

This is the content of `/usr/share/i18n/locales`:

```
de_DE                  translit_combining
en_US                  translit_compat
i18n                   translit_font
iso14651_t1            translit_fraction
iso14651_t1_common     translit_hangul
iso14651_t1_pinyin     translit_narrow
translit_circle        translit_neutral
translit_cjk_compat    translit_small
translit_cjk_variants  translit_wide
```

So it appears that the files `en_GB` and `i18n_ctype` are indeed missing (although I am not sure if they should be in this folder)

Also, if I go to the *Settings* -> *Region and Language*, I cannot change the *Language* (it says `Unspecified [ANSI_X3.4-1968]`. If I click on it, there is nothing to select in the *Select Language* pop-up.

I found online that the problem could be with `glibc`(and according to the history `glibc` was reinstalled during the update I ran `[2020-08-11T18:49:33+0200] [ALPM] reinstalled glibc (2.31-5)`). However, I do not know how to fix that. There is no reinstall button for glibc in the package manager, and I do not want to do any experiments where I could end up in a bigger mess.

Is there a way to reinstall/reset the language files?

### Update

I use `NoExtract` in `/etc/pacman.conf` to save space on the hard drive, like described in the [Arch wiki] (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Installing_only_content_in_required_languages)

```
NoExtract = usr/share/help/* !usr/share/help/en*
NoExtract = usr/share/gtk-doc/html/*
NoExtract = usr/share/locale/* usr/share/X11/locale/* usr/share/i18n/* opt/google/chrome/locales/*
NoExtract = !*locale*/en*/* !usr/share/i18n/charmaps/UTF-8.gz !usr/share/*locale*/locale.*
NoExtract = !usr/share/*locales/en_US !usr/share/*locales/i18n !usr/share/*locales/iso*
NoExtract = !usr/share/*locales/trans*
NoExtract = !*locale*/de*/* !usr/share/i18n/charmaps/UTF-8.gz !usr/share/*locale*/locale.*
NoExtract = !usr/share/*locales/de_DE !usr/share/*locales/i18n !usr/share/*locales/iso*
NoExtract = !usr/share/*locales/trans*
NoExtract = usr/share/qt4/translations/*
NoExtract = usr/share/man/* !usr/share/man/man*
NoExtract = usr/share/vim/vim*/lang/*
NoExtract = usr/lib/libreoffice/help/en-US/*
```

I wonder if this is part of the problem, maybe when glibc was reinstalled some files were skipped.

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit `/etc/locale.gen`:

   Uncomment the line with your:

   ```
   locale en_US.UTF-8
   ```
2. run `sudo locale-gen`

Credit: https://nanxiao.me/en/fix-locale-configuration-issue-on-arch-linux/

Comment: That line is already uncommented, the problem is that the `en_GB` and `i18n_ctype` get deleted and I guess `en_US` is depending on them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution now. I don't think this is the best way, but it seems to work for me.

I downloaded the [glibc package](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/) and manually copied the  missing files (`en_GB` and `i18n_ctype`) to `/usr/share/i18n/locales/`.

And then run `sudo locale-gen`

Answer (score 0):

You can get back your `/etc/locale.gen` by re-installing the `glibc` package. This will generate a new file on installation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by `KDE Plasma Settings Manager` - which configured the locale to not existing configuration.

During the Manjaro installation, I picked `Finland/English` there, because it was available. Why not? It resolves to `fi_EN.UTF-8` which turns out to be at least a nonsense, since `glibc` does not contain such a combo.

You can list the `glibc` languages checking its package files like that:

```bash
pacman -Ql glibc | grep fi_
```

Which in my case showed those two:

```bash
glibc /usr/share/i18n/locales/fi_FI
glibc /usr/share/i18n/locales/fi_FI@euro
```

`fi_FI` is the proper one, not `fi_EN` neither `fi_US`. Shame on you, Plasma.

Replace the `grep fi_` in the command above to find your language, like for Polish: `grep pl_`, German: `grep de_` and so on.

Then compare it to the result of `locale` command call. In my case I needed to correct it by editing `/etc/locale.gen`. You can follow Manjaro's troubleshooting:

https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Locale

Or rather, in the Holly Arch Wiki:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/locale